# Scraping the web : data separator needed

Tags: ruby

I am trying to scrape the allocine website as an exercice and my output is the following :

```
Movie Name 
Rating 1 Rating 2
```

Example :

```
Coco
4,14,6

Forrest Gump
2,64,6
```

it should be instead :

```
Movie Name

Rating 1

Rating 2
```

Hope you can help me !

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

array = []


for i in 1..10
  url = "http://www.allocine.fr/film/meilleurs//?page=#{i}"
  html_file = open(url).read
  html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_file)


  html_doc.search('.img_side_content').each do |element|
    array << element.search('.no_underline').inner_text
    array << element.search('.note').inner_text
  end





end
puts array


csv_options = { col_sep: ',', force_quotes: true, quote_char: '"' }
filepath    = 'allocine.csv'

CSV.open(filepath, 'wb', csv_options) do |csv|
  array.each { |item| csv << [item] }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to parse the notes, this is why they appear without a space in the console.
What you can do is to add an `each` and fill your array like this :

```
element.search('.note').each do |data|
  array << data.inner_text
end
```